# In the definition of a quotient group, does the subgroup have to be normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H \leq G$. Does $H$ need to be a normal subgroup to have the quotient group $G/H$?

---

#### Progress

I think yes. By definition, a subgroup $H$ is normal if and only if it is the kernel of some homomorphism. Moreover, $G/H$ makes sense if and only if $H$ is the kernel of some homomorphism. Putting these together, we obtain the answer. Does this seem right?

Comment: What do you think? What have you learned about normal subgroups and quotient groups?

Comment: I think yes. By definition, a subgroup $H$ is normal if and only if it is the kernel of some homomorphism. Moreover, $G/H$ makes sense if and only if $H$ is the kernel of some homomorphism. Putting these together, we obtain the answer. Does this seem right?

Comment: Basically, yes, though I'd put the order somewhat differently. Your first statement is absolutely true. And $G/H$ makes sense if and only if the coset multiplication is well-defined, which turns out to be true if and only if $H$ is normal.

Comment: I agree that the coset multiplication is the crucial thing. If the subgroup is not normal,  there is no reasonable qay to define the multiplication operation in the quotient structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normality is required. This answer starts by assuming that $H$ is not normal but that $G/H$ forms a group, and finds a contradiction.

So, suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ but *not* normal in $G$, and suppose that the multiplication of $G$ inherited by $G/H$ gives a group: $G/H$ with multiplication $(gH)\cdot (hH)=(gh)H$ forms a group.

Firstly, note that the element $H(=1H)$ is the identity of the "group" $G/H$, as $gH\cdot H=gH$ for all $g\in G$ (and in a group, if you have a right identity then it is also a left identity).

Now, as $H$ is not normal in $G$ there exists some $g\in G$ such that $gHg^{-1}\neq H$. Consider $(gH)\cdot(g^{-1}H)$. As the multiplication in $G$ is inherited by $G/H$, this has to be equal to the identity of the "group" $G/H$. Hence, $gHg^{-1}H=H$. This implies that$^{\dagger}$ $gHg^{-1}=H$, a contradiction.

---

$^{\dagger}$I'll leave the implication as an exercise. You have that the map $H\times H\rightarrow H$, $(h_1, h_2)\mapsto gh_1g^{-1}h_2$ is a bijection. Use this to show that $H\rightarrow H$, $h_1\mapsto gh_1g^{-1}$ is also a bijection.